# Terminating a Share Picker app on load complete

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've implemented a [Share Picker Extender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967563(v=VS.92).aspx) (which lets you share a photo from the Pictures hub to your app via a special token), and would like to close the app once the user has clicked on the button to upload the photo, as the built-in Facebook app does.

I'm aware of the [many questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=windows%20phone%207%20exit%20app) re terminating apps - I'm just wondering if I'm missing something for Share Picker Extenders ...  Telling the user "Now press the back button" seems pretty ugly, but perhaps it is the only (certification worthy) way. If you've implemented a Share Picker extender, what have you done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out a good way to handle this either.  I detect that users have gone back to my first page and say "Click here to go to our main app" and "Click back to go pack to Pictures".  And if they click the first one, `Navigate("MainPage.xaml");`.  You have to make sure you don't accidentally prevent them from leaving.  I asked this question awhile ago in [this](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/72452.aspx) thread and got no response.